# load variables from a local file in ansible

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

I want ansible to run several shell commonds(like: rm/ yum install ) over remote servers. But instead of putting commonds inside the playbook, I want ansible to read shell commands from a file , thereby other people only need to swap the commands in this file with no need to know how playbook works.
file could in any type of extension like txt/yml/json,

```
[list.txt]

yum install ntp -y
rm -rf /app/tst.txt
service ntpd start
```

Is there a module that loads this yml/json file and register every element as variables hence i can use it dynamically in playbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use [include_vars](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html) module.

If you want only pure shell commands to be executed without any processing, there is a [script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html) module that takes a given file, transfers it to target machine and executes.